# Browser's back button causes data not to load at all

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to make an app using angular, angularfire2, and firebase.
I've generated a service to handle all the firebase stuff I need, and two components: Posts and Post as well.

This is my service class:

```
export class FirebaseService {

  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.postsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts');
    this.posts = this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
  }

  getPosts() {
    return this.posts;
  }

  getPost(id: string) {
  }

}
```

And this is my Posts component:

```
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[];

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //console.log('ngOnInit ran...');
    this.firebaseService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      //console.log(posts);
      this.posts = posts;
    })
  }

}
```

And Posts component template:

```
<div *ngIf="posts?.length > 0; else noPosts">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts" class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <a [routerLink]="['/posts/', post.id]">{{ post.title }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #noPosts>
  There are no posts in the database.
</ng-template>
```

I will try to describe what is the problem.

When I click a link to go to single Post, and then click back in the browser to see the list of Posts again, the Posts are not loaded until the page is refreshed.

When I click back in the browser I only see "There are no posts in the database.".

I have no idea why this happens so maybe you could help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to somehow figure it out and I found a solution.

In my service I did:

```
constructor() {
  console.log('constructor ran');
}
getPosts() {
  console.log('getPosts() called');
}
```

And realized that the constructor is ran only once, either on page enter or refresh.

The working service:

```
export class FirebaseService {

  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor(public afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.postsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts');
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.posts = this.postsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    });
    return this.posts;
  }

  getPost(id: string) {
  }

}
```